# using $$ in a post causes strange number series to appear

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

So, in one of my recent Code Review questions, I have a function `$$` and posting it (even inside the code block) causes the following issue.

So you can see that my code looks like the following:

[image: imagefilter1]

but then in the post:

[image: strangenumbers]

All the space between the two dollar dollar blocks is seemingly replaced with a series of numbers, a key perhaps. (I blurred it out, just in case)

Comment: Well, doesn't happen [here on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236615/152859).

Comment: IIRC, CodeReview has MathJax enabled. This triggers special formatting on `$$`.

Comment: "Let's enable MathJax", they said, "what could go wrong?" [they said](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/mathjax-on-codereview)...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have confused the renderer with a missing `<!-- end snippet -->` before `<!-- language: lang-css -->`.

When I remove the

```
\<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false --\>

\<!-- language: lang-js --\>
```

<sub>(ignore the backslashes above please, these were needed to get it rendered halfway concise here also)</sub>

comments, or put the `<!-- end snippet -->` before the `<!-- language: lang-css -->` it just renders as it should.

Not sure, if this should be considered a bug, or is just normal behavior for runnable code snippets.

See a demo [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270878/186472) please.

Code within snippets seems to be handled differently as within standard code formatting.

---

Though the CSS and HTML code seem to be intended to be part of your snippet. Unfortunately I can't tell how to switch the language within, but at least we have diagnosed the reason now.

Well, if I remove the additional `<!-- language: ... -->` entirely [like here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270881/186472), the snippet is runnable (though I'm not sure if it runs as intended).

The reason is likely that the `<!-- language: ... -->` comments are primarily meant to influence rendering markdown, but are interpreted differently within runnable code snippets.

Comment: Except that's not the case on the post. See [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113931/image-filter-client) for the original post.

Comment: @Quill Sure? I've been working at exactly that post of yours, before you have edited it.

Comment: It still comes up even after I added a space before the html lang tag, also in that demo on the sandbox post, you joined the three, I think that might be part of it.

Comment: @Quill Adding spaces doesn't help obviously, and I didn't even mentioned so. It looks just like you simply cannot mix HTML language tags within code snippets. These use different renderers. Either omit the surrounding code snippet tags, or remove the language tags as mentioned in my answer.